# Member Group permissions and editing comments — can't get it to work

Tags: members, comments, permissions, groups

I've set up my templates to add in-place comment editing and deletion. It's working great, and should be a useful feature.

However: Now that I'm ready to roll it out I'm attempting to test it with non-Super Admin users… and they can't see the Edit and Delete buttons.

Here's the code in question:

```
{if can_moderate_comment}
<a href="#" class="edit-link">Edit</a>
<a href="#" class="mod-link">Delete</a>
{/if}
```

(I've also tried `if editable`.)

The editing time limit is 0 (I tried setting it to something other than 0 without results).

It's obviously a permissions thing. but I can't find any combination of Member Group permissions that lets a Member see the Edit/Delete buttons on their own posts, but not on every other comment as well. I think I've tried just about every combination you can make in the Comment Administration section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the "set to 0 for no limit" instruction is BS. I've had success using {if editable} and setting an arbitrarily *high* number like 9999999.

Comment: Aha. There seem to be two bugs here, actually: 1. The "0" setting *was* BS; 2. It took a couple tries for a new setting to stick.